# Comparing arguments with an arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, arguments

Please help me with this code; I am trying to compare arguments with an array elements and return when it matches, I don't know what is wrong with this code, it returns **1** rather than an **array** , thanks.

```
const removeFromArray = function() {
var delArgs = [] ;

//convert the arguments to an array called 'args'.
var args = Array.from(arguments);
var Arr = args[0];

//using foreach() and forloop to compare arguments with Arr elements.
Arr.forEach(function(x){
    for (var j=1 ; j < args.length ; j++){
        if(x == args[j]){
            delArgs = delArgs.push(x);
        }

    }

 });
     return delArgs;
}
```

removeFromArray([1,2,3,4,5,6] , 5);
1

Comment: Ok let  me clarify my doubt here as well. How does removeFromArray function take parameters?

Comment: `delArgs.push` returns _**number**_ (array's length), not array

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> delArgs = delArgs.push(x);
> ```

You're overwriting `delArgs` with the return value from `push`, which is [the new length of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Don't do that.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning explicitly that the fix is just to put `delArgs.push(x)`, without the `delArgs =`

Answer (score 1):

since the question is already answered, you could use this for shorter code

```js
const removeFromArray = (array, ...args) => {
  return args.filter( arg => array.includes(arg)  )
}

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 5,6));
```